# Synonyms for 'conference attendees'

Tags: synonyms

I'm trying to think of the best way to casually say 'conference attendees'. Any ideas?

Comment: If it's a prestigious enough conference, maybe the attendees are mostly *delegates*.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't want to be that formal. One of the other conference execs used that word initially and I didn't like it but I couldn't think of anything better than conference attendees. Given our target market it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Is it in order to say that the persons going to the conference are the _attenders_ and the conference is the _attendee_ (even the spell-checker is objecting to _attenders_)? Or am I flogging a long-dead horse here?

Comment: @Brian Hooper: I don't think that would be in order. So far as I'm aware, *attendee* is simply the new upcoming synonym for *attender*. They both mean a person who is present at an event, as opposed to *attendant*, being a person who looks after the needs of others (possibly including attendees at OP's conference). I don't think there's any word based on *attend* to identify the actual event/venue.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I think *attended* works for the event/venue ‒ although a bit clunky.

Comment: @jwpat7: *Definitely* a bit clunky, if not worse - but you can certainly speak of a *well-attended event* (maybe even *venue*, though that might be flakey). In the end, I think calling an event/venue *the attended* is no better than calling your car *the driven*. You just wouldn't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can call them *participants*.

Comment: I suppose participants works. There really aren't a lot of words for this.